# Syntaxhighlighter shows up in single line

Tags: html, playframework, syntax-highlighting

I have a scenario where-in I fetch some text from the database which is formatted using HTML as below:

```
public static void main(String args[ ]) { <br> int x =10;}
```

I'm using syntax highlighter to do some highlighting. The String above will be fetched from the database, and rendered in the html page using the pre tag as shown below:

```
<p><pre class="brush: java;">@exam.description</pre></p>
```

Where exam.description will contain the HTML formatted source code that is shown above. The resultant HTML rendered is as shown below in the screenshot!

[image: Rendered HTML]

How to ensue that the HTML tags inside the source code are respected as HTML tags? I checked the configuration options for the Syntax Highlighter and there seems to be none that I could use to escape the HTML! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make much sense, maybe you should rephrase it, in any case:

```
<p><pre class="brush: java;">Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\n</pre></p>
```

Will return the data in multiple lines, and

```
<p><pre class="brush: java;">Line 1<br>\nLine 2\nLine 3\n</pre></p>
```

Will also return multiple lines and add an extra line between `Line 1` and `Line 2`.

So in any case, your code should work UNLESS you are escaping the data returned from the function (java function), and the `<` and `>` (or just one of them) are escaped